# BTRFS, Files on a single drive in array but keep 2-parity?

Tags: linux, hard-drive, raid, software-raid, btrfs

Is it possible to setup a BTRFS array of disk but tell it to keep files on individual disks instead of stripping them and still keep a 2-parity?

The idea is that if three drives die, the files on the remaining disks will still be readable. If <3 drives die, I can recover the missing disks without a problem.

I know keeping files on single disks works with -d single, but having a recovery record on top of that would be very nice.

Comment: I think in general case that is impossible to manage. For example, you decide to put one 3GB file on your 2GB+2GB volume. Theoretically that should be possible, but in your case `btrfs` should report an error once you reach 2GB limit (the maximum that your single drive). The tweak becomes more difficult if you have underlying drives (devices) of different sizes. So, no way :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question is a little unclear, but let me describe what BTRFS will do.

The assumption here is that you have a single BTRFS file system with multiple disks in it.

First, "-d single" does NOT keep all of the blocks of a file together on a single disk.  Any file can be scattered across several disks.  What "-d single" means is that there is only one single copy of any block in a file; there are no extra copies.  The blocks can be on any disks.

BTRFS works in disk chunks of 1GB each.  If your file is less than 1GB in size, then it will very often be in a single chunk, on one drive.  It will generally be like this when the file is first created, or when it is defragmented.  However, if the file is modified, changed parts of the file can be placed anywhere.

BTRFS will generally try to spread chunks around to balance the disk space and I/O activity across the member disks in the filesystem.  So if your file is bigger than 1GB, it WILL be spread across multiple drives.

One very important thing to remember: RAID is NOT a backup strategy.  If you really need files to survive the loss of 3 drives, you need backups of some sort.  Whether that is replication to another system, or DVD-RW disks, or LTO tapes, or whatever, you should not depend on any form of RAID or filesystem alone to ensure that your data survives.

If you really want to make sure you have whole intact files on your surviving disks in event of other disk failures, you can look into GlusterFS.  But it's another level of complexity beyond BTRFS.

Comment: I have a full backup now. When I asked this question I didn't. This question happened after I got slapped by a BTRFS Z2 going to read-only after an add drive failure. I've used a pooling solution but I'm looking into using BTRFS again over dm-crypt. Thank's for the explanation.